# mysql LEFT JOIN query with max value in where state

Tags: mysql

ok so I have a database and a query built up something like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c03e8/11

however I can't for the world of me figure out how to reach my end goal which is to hide the tenth row as that one has the `"tamed" = 1`

would anyone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple just do a select of your select and add an additional where

```
SELECT id, name, level, location, tamed
FROM (
-- your inside select here
) as temp
WHERE temp.tamed <> 1
```

Comment: I would prefer not doing an extra select as I'm a bit scared that this query will turn slow quite fast as I already have close to 10 000 posts in the info table and steadily growing

Comment: ok... the current query does not have any value in the tenth row for tamed.. so what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm sorry the url I added hyad a test with a where state in it added the correct one now

Comment: @Touchpad Btw, i would recommend running the outer select query to see how it affects performance. run your query and then run this one. instead of using multiple wheres, an outer select could actually be a lot faster... its not a correlated query so it wont do additional computations

Comment: If that doesn't work you can always do a join where the tamed is not 1 ... you really don't need left joins from the data you provided.. inner joins or left joins wont matter because your cases put in the nulls which causes all rows to be returned

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query ... 10th row is gone. remove the condition from where clause and add to join condition. Also, I made your first join type is `INNER JOIN` rather a `LEFT JOIN`. So that, when the condition doesn't match that row will not be returned at all.
Your fiddle with my updated query here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/835b3b/28

```
SELECT  `t1` . * , MAX(
CASE WHEN  `info_types`.`name` =  "level"
THEN  `t1_info`.`value`
ELSE NULL
END ) AS  "level", 
MAX(
CASE WHEN  `info_types`.`name` =  "location"
THEN  `t1_info`.`value`
ELSE NULL
END ) AS  "location", 
MAX(
CASE WHEN  `info_types`.`name` =  "tamed"
THEN  `t1_info`.`value`
ELSE NULL
END ) AS  "tamed"
FROM `t1` 
INNER JOIN  `t1_info` 
ON  `t1`.`id` =  `t1_info`.`t1_id`
AND `t1`.`id` !=10
LEFT JOIN  `info_types` 
ON `t1_info`.`type_id` = `info_types`.`id`
and `t1_info`.`value` !=1       
GROUP BY  `t1`.`id`;
```

**EDIT:**

In your posted fiddle query, change the second left join to look like below, with that the `tammed` column for 10th row also will be `NULL`. Else, go for a outer select as suggested in other answer.

```
LEFT JOIN  `info_types` 
ON `t1_info`.`type_id` = `info_types`.`id`
AND `t1_info`.`type_id` != 3
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the 10th row because it has tamed = 1 NOT because it's the 10th row

Comment: @Touchpad, if you check carefully; you are trying to remove the 10th row from t1 table. That's what I understood from your fiddle.

Comment: "... is to hide the tenth row as that one has the `"tamed" = 1`"

Comment: taht removes the one with level 1  aswell